# What are the pros and cons of estimating the lognormal distribution parameters with maximum likelihood estimation and least squares estimation?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, lognormal-distribution

I have come across an Excel model that estimates the lognormal distribution parameters with maximum likelihood estimation and least squares estimation. The least squares estimation is fitted to the empirical cumulative distribution. What are the pros and cons of each method?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the "least squares estimation" method is precisely doing? Or provide a link to the description?

Comment: Least squares as in the method used in regression analysis. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares

Comment: Least squares minimizes the summation of squared error. You solve $\min_\theta \sum_i e_i^2$ where $e_i$ is some function of $\theta$. My question is what's the error you're minimizing? You say "the least squares estimation is fitted to the empirical cumulative distribution." What does this precisely mean?

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd say you want to use the maximum likelihood estimate for the parameters of the lognormal distribution.

Comment: say I have five samples X1, X2, X3, X4 and X5 with an empirical cumulative distribution of 10%, 30%, 80%, 90% and 97%. a lognormal distribution is fitted to the sample such that the least squares difference between the empirical cumulative distribution and the fitted lognormal cumulative distribution is minimised... sorry if I have not been clear.

Comment: @Matthew Gunn : I agree MLE seems more suitable. I am just curious why the model builder would want to estimate the lognormal parameters with LSE...

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  Within Excel, least squares tends to be easier to implement as it has had built-in functions for the necessary calculations.  As far as I am aware, any attempts at MLE would need to be programmed.

Comment: @Tavrock MLE here is trivial. Let $X_i$ be drawn from the [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for $i=1,\ldots, n$. Let $x_i = \log X_i$, hence $x_i$ follows the normal distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. The MLE estimate for the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of either the lognormal distribution for $X$ or the normal distribution for $x$ is given by $\hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i (x_i - \hat{\mu})^2$.